# How to add text to the textfield inside dataChangedListener in codename one?

Tags: textbox, codenameone, settext

I am using `TextField` and on `addDataChangedListener` I am trying to add some character to the text field if length of the text field is 2 but it is not working for me.can you please help me how to achieve my requirement.

For this thing i use below mention code,

```
text.addDataChangedListener(new DataChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {                       
          if(text.getText().length() == 2)
              text.setText(text.getText() + "/");                      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `DataChangedListener` use `ActionListener` which got triggered when the TextField lost focus.

You can't modify the content of a TextField while typing because of its Async state.

```
text.addActionListener(evt -> {                       
    if(text.getText().length() == 2)
        text.setText(text.getText() + "/");                      
    }
});
```

Comment: On re-reading this I'm guessing that what he is interested in is masking: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/validation-regex-masking.html